# infinite Loop useEffect

Tags: reactjs

```
const Weather = () => {

const [Datos, SetDatos] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
        const AxiosData = () => {
            axios.get(`https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/images/search?limit=5&page=10&order=Desc`)
            .then(res => {
                SetDatos(res.data);
                console.log(Datos);
                
            })
            .catch(err =>{
                console.log(err)
            })
        }
        AxiosData()
    }, []);
  
   return(

    <div>
    ....
    </div>
    
   )


}
```

estoy probando consumir una Apis para mostrar imágenes aleatoria de perros. el problema es que el useEffect rendereriza infinitamente.

listo ya actualize el post y agrege el código completo asi es como tengo el codigo actualmente

Comment: Esta pieza de código parece funcionar bien, si pudieras compartir el código del componente completo, saludos

Comment: Podrías compartir el mensaje de error que te arroja por consola?